# CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource:

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I have been following along with AWS documentation and example code for DynamoDB use but have come to halt in my progress. After setting up my Cognito User Pool/Identity and IAM Roles correctly, I can no longer Query on my DynamoDB table. I am able to run a scan, delete, and GetItem without problems but cannot run a Query. Is my unauthorized IAM role setup correctly to run Queries on my DynamoDB table?

IAM Unauthorized Role:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1474743569000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1474743616000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Query Function:

```
func getQuery(){
    //performing a query

    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    //queryExpression.scanIndexForward = 1
    queryExpression.indexName = "Pay"

    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "Company = :Company AND Pay > :Pay"

    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
        ":Company" : "TestCompany",
        ":Pay" : 0];

    dynamoDBObjectMapper .query(DDBTableRow.self, expression: queryExpression) .continue(with: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), with: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to query a test table.", message: task.error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            })
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                self.pagniatedOutput = task.result! as AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
            }
            //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainSegue", sender: self)
        }
        return nil
    })


}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Update #2:
Adding in Exception Received:

```
    Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain Code=6 "(null)" 

    UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException, 

    Message=User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/Cognito_testUserUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is 
    not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1/index/Pay})
```

Update #3:
The issue was with the Resource parameter in my IAM role. I made one minor change and am now able to query.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1474743569000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1/index/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1474743616000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable2",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable2/index/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your permissions look fine to me. Can you share the exact exception message, also can you verify what table are you trying to query?

Comment: @RachitDhall I am querying MyTable1. I have updated my post with the exception I am receiving. Thanks!

Comment: @RachitDhall Resolved the issue with the changes made in my updated post. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update #3: The issue was with the Resource parameter in my IAM role. I made one minor change and am now able to query.

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1474743569000",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1",
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable1/index/*"
    ]
},
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1474743616000",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable2",
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable2/index/*"
    ]
}
]
```